# How to plot a shape on a chart if alert conditions are true

Tags: pine-script

This is the code I am currently working on for an alert system. I am learning as I go so feel free to correct any mistakes even if it's irrelevant to my question.

```
//WORK IN PROGRESS

//@version=4
study("Multiple Indicator Alert WIP", overlay = true)


//Custom inputs for each indicator
rsilen = input(title="RSI Length", type=input.integer, defval=14)
emalen1 = input(title="1st EMA Length", type=input.integer, defval=12, minval=1)
emalen2 = input(title="2nd EMA Length", type=input.integer, defval=24)
emalen3 = input(title="3rd EMA Length", type=input.integer, defval=30)
emalen4 = input(title="4th EMA Length", type=input.integer, defval=60)
DIlen = input(title="DI Length", type=input.integer, defval=7)
ADXSmoothlen=input(title="ADX Smoothing", type=input.integer, defval=7)

//variables for all indicators (incomplete)
RSI = rsi(close, rsilen)
EMA1 = ema(close, emalen1)
EMA2 = ema(close, emalen2)
EMA3 = ema(close, emalen3)
EMA4 = ema(close, emalen4)
[diplus, diminus, adx] = dmi(DIlen, ADXSmoothlen)
price = close

bullishcondition = RSI > 50 and EMA1 > EMA2 and price > EMA1 + EMA2 and diplus > diminus

alertcondition(condition= bullishcondition, message="All conditions bullish for 4 hour chart")
```

I am trying to make it so that it plots something on the chart whenever the alert conditions are met. Maybe a little triangle or something. I've read that using an `if` statement isn't possible with `plot()` argument, and I've seen examples on how to do this but I'm still confused. I want to do this so I can see if the code works without having to actually set an alert and wait for it to fire. Thanks so much in advance.

I used to have the conditions in the `alertcondition` argument, but I decided it was more efficient to just make it a variable so I can tweak the variable and make it easier to plot when the variable is `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to plot a shape you can either use `plotshape` or `label.new`, it is also possible to use `plotchar` and `plotarrow` for arrows.

`plotshape` is generally the best option and can be used as follows:

```
plotshape(bullishcondition,style=shape.triangleup,location=location.belowbar,color=#0cb51a)
```

`label.new` can be used with an `if` statement.

```
label l = na
n = bar_index
if bullishcondition
    l := label.new(n,low,color=#0cb51a,style=label.style_arrowup)
```

In order to plot a shape with a position that is relative to other series of observations use `location.absolute` in `plotshape` as follows:

```
plotshape(bullishcondition ? rsi : na,style=shape.square,location=location.absolute,color=#0cb51a)
```

here a square is plotted at the value of the rsi when `bullishcondition` is true.

Comment: Okay so I copied what you put using 'plotshape()' but tweaked it a bit, it seems it was simpler than I thought. I do have another issue, when i try to plot the RSI on the chart, it seems to work, but when I try to plot the EMA, it doesn't seem to do anything. It just makes a flat line at the bottom. Both also plot over the chart, with the price invisible.

Do you have any idea what may be going wrong here, I'm confident that I have the right syntax and everything, I have no clue.

Comment: Ah you know what, I'm stupid. The RSI isn't supposed to go on the main chart. Ignore the question xD

But the triangles don't seem to be showing up anywhere.

Comment: Okay, so I applied it to the chart, changing "rsi" to "RSI" to match the variable's name. However, I still don't see anything being plotted, I have set overlay to true. I think I understand how the code works and there doesn't seem to be any issues which is why it's baffling. I swear I'll punch myself if it was something really stupid I hadn't thought of. I'm sorry if it seems like I'm asking too many questions.

Comment: I think the condition `bullishcondition` will never be true because of `price > EMA1 + EMA2`, maybe that you wanted to use `price > avg(EMA1,EMA2)`. That's why no shapes are appearing.

Comment: Actually you know what that gives me an idea, I've already set the condition for EMA1 to be above EMA2, I don't also need to have price above both, because EMA1 would already be at the top. Thanks for the suggestion, I really didn't think about it. I'll try it out.

Comment: Alright it seems to be working now, it is popping up a lot but that's because the conditions are few and broad, there are several more conditions that need to be added. Thanks for your help. Remind me to punch myself.

Comment: No punching here, only learning is allowed ^^ You are welcome for the help.